# Scrolling through calendar and selecting a date

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

On this site, you cannot just send in a date, but it forces you to click on the date in the calendar picker, and for some reason I cannot solve it.  Any ideas?  Here is where I left off:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-date-toggle"]').click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rod-date-toggle"]'))).send_keys("4/1/2020")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rodToDateTxt"]'))).send_keys("4/10/2020")

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-submit-search"]').click()
```

Doesn't seem to A. send in keys.  And when I did get this part solved, it doesn't work unless I click on the actual date in the calendar.   Confusing!

Answer (score 1):

After you enter a date in the box, you need to **close the date-picker** By sending Enter or Return keys:

```
YourElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Import package :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```